# In PHP how to add a greeting that greets someone after a login with their first name from the sql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been trying to create a greeting after a user logs in that says "Welcome, first name (dynamic)." so when the user logs in they are greeted with their name. For some reasont it has not been working out. I am new at php so this may be a simple error. Any assist or advice would be useful. Thanks.

**main code**

```
session_start();


$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'username';
$mysql_password = 'password';
$mysql_database = 'db_users2015';

$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die ("Couldn't connect");

echo "<BR>Connection Successful";

  //to put data into database
  //select database
  $db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect) 
  or die ("Couldn't connect to the database");

//frontend and backend data processing
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];



//To see if email is registered
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email= '{$_POST['email']}'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_result($sql_result, 0)<1)
 {
die("<BR>Email address not found");
}

else{
    echo "Login Successful!";
}


//To check if email and password match

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
password ='$password' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$_SESSION['firstname']= $_POST['firstname'];


if (mysql_result($result, 0) > 0){

    echo "<BR>Login Successful, welcome";
    echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
}

if (mysql_result($result, 0) < 1){

    echo 'wrong password/username combo';
}






?>
```

```html
<HTML>

  <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Programming</TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="homework2.css"> 

    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

      <!-- CSS for http://the7.dream-demo.com/ -->

      <div id="container">
        
        <div id="header">
          <div class="menuitem"> <a href="home.html">Home</a> </div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="products.html">Products</a></div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="cases.html">Case Studies</a></div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="bodycontent">
          
          <div id="banner">
           <div id="bannerleft"> <h1> We make you better athletes. Find out how! </h1> </div>
           <div id="signin"> 
             
             <form class="well form-inline" action="login.php" method="post">

              <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email"  name="email" >
              <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password" name="password">
              <br><br>

<!--
  If you do not want to use twitter bootstrap css then you should uncomment next 6 lines and uncomment the
  above 2 lines that provide input boxes

     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
     <br>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
     <br>
    -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="logmein" value="Log In">
  </form>
  
</div>

</div>
<div id="featurestrip"> 

  
  <div id="signup">

    <form action="signup.php" method="post">

     
     <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
     <input type="text" name="signup-firstname" id="signup-firstname">
     <br>

     <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
     <input type="text" name="signup-lastname" id="signup-lastname">
     <br>

     <label for="email">Email:&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
     <input type="text" name="signup-email" id="signup-email">
     <br>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="signup-password" id="signup-password">
     <br>
     <label for="password">Reconfirm Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="signup-repassword" id="signup-repassword">
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="signmeup" id="signmeup" value="Sign Me Up!">
   </form>

 </div>

 <div id="featureright"> <p>Sign up and find out more on how we can help. Pricing starts at $19.95 a month. </p>
  <p><h3>Premium service starts at $49.95.</h3></p>

</div>   


</div>
<div id="corefeatures"> 



 <img height="200px" src="http://www.hockeymanitoba.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ltad-model.jpg">
</div>

<div id="testimonials"> Testimonial
  <img height="200px" src="http://www.neuroexplosion.com/storage/development%20model%20jpeg.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1305662626397">

  <img height="200px" src="http://www.phecanada.ca/sites/default/files/physical_literacy/LTAD_FMS.jpg">
</div>
       <!--
       <div id="portfolio"> Portfolio</div>
       <div id="skills"> Skills</div>
     -->
   </div>
   
   <div id="footer">Copyright Notice. All Rights Reserved. 2014</div>

 </div>

 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

**2nd php code edit**

```
<?php

session_start();


$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'username';
$mysql_password = 'password';
$mysql_database = 'db_users2015';

$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die ("Couldn't connect");

echo "<BR>Connection Successful";

  //to put data into database
  //select database
  $db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect) 
  or die ("Couldn't connect to the database");

//frontend and backend data processing
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];



//To see if email is registered
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email= '{$_POST['email']}'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_result($sql_result, 0)<1)
 {
die("<BR>Email address not found");
}

else{
    echo "Login Successful!";
}


//To check if email and password match

$sql = "SELECT(*) FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
password ='$password' LIMIT 1";
$userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['firstname]' = $userdata['firstname'];


if (mysql_result($result, 0) > 0){

    echo "<BR>Login Successful, welcome";
    echo $firstname;
}

if (mysql_result($result, 0) < 1){

    echo 'wrong password/username combo';
}






?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under `//To check if email and password match`

put this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
password ='$password' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  $firstname = $row["firstname"];
  echo "<BR>Login Successful, welcome";
  echo $firstname;
}else{   
  echo 'wrong password/username combo';
}
```

Comment: I changed the code to this but for some reason it still just says welcome and doesn't show the first name from the sql database

Comment: is  `echo "<BR>Login Successful, welcome"`  executed?

Comment: Yes, so I end up with this message fromecho when I login. Connection SuccessfulLogin Successful!
Login Successful, welcome    ---- but for some reason first name is not pulling from the database

Comment: in this case, you not pulling the `firstname` from the database. it's from the  input from html form

Comment: gotcha, i added my html, I thought it could be pulled from the html but I am guessing it may be easier to pull from the database? Thanks for the assist.

Comment: that's not what I meant lol.  just pull it from database if `firstname` is a column

Comment: sorry, code is a bit rubbish. First few days learning. "firstname" is a column in mysql, how would I pull it from there to add it then?

Comment: checking now one moment.

Comment: You are a life saver! This worked perfectly. I gotta process what it is doing but its working great. Thanks so much!

Comment: Will do, thank you again. I'm going to go through the w3 courses soon.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Been here

```
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$_SESSION['firstname']= $_POST['firstname'];
```

You are Trying to get First Name from login page html form. but i don't remember if any login page ever have First name field. so you should get first name from database and put it in `$_SESSION['firstname']`

Hope to be clear enough. :)

To get data out of database
Change this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password ='$password' LIMIT 1
```

To This

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password ='$password' LIMIT 1

$userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $userdata['firstname'];
```

This will do the trick

Comment: You are right, it only asks for email and password. So how would I put the first name in from the database with php?

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
password ='$password' LIMIT 1` Change this to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
password ='$password' LIMIT 1` And fetch data using `$userdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: and than you can use `$_SESSION['firstname]' = $userdata['firstname'] ` be sure you use the column name from database if it's otherthan `firstname` than change `$userdata['column_name']`

Comment: Please use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` isntead of `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` as you use mysql not mysqli @ruwadidr

Comment: I added the edited code in my original post labled 2nd php code edit. I added the edits you mentioned, for some reason the code is broke and showing a blank page now when attempting login. Could you see if there was an error where I entered it?

Comment: Put `$userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` after `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); `

Answer (score 0):

the place where you set your firstname should be changed with this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['firstname']= $row['firstname'];
```

set firstname by fetching results from database because $_POST['firstname'] does not exists in your page.

Thanks.

Comment: Changed `code`$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['firstname]' = $userdata['firstname'];`code` to   `code`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['firstname']= $row['firstname']; `code` like you mentioned but it still isn't pulling from database, I get a welcome message like before just no name.